# Emulating a defective LCD from a device and use another LCD

Tags: stm32, c, lcd

I have a device which has a defective LCD that is not produced anymore.
Source info: https://www.mpc-forums.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=138491&start=30

The socket from the schematic diagram is following:
[image]

Someone tried to do the same thing and captured the data, and it's as follows:
[image]

This is the CPU that controls the LCD :
[image]

My approach is to use STM32F4 with parallel slave and use DMA but I have the following questions:

1. Where is the clock signal to be fed to STM32F4 so that I can capture the data bus correctly?
2. After capturing the data, I'm sure that the CPU from that device issues Address Control/Data, how do I differentiate between them ?
3. After successful capturing the data, how do I collect the bytes and make a picture then forward it to another LCD ?

Schematic :
https://www.mediafire.com/file/muuwm9qvfvgr9qm/MPCSchematic.pdf/file

Comment: you say "tried the same", so, did they examine communication with the exact same display? Also, please name (and if possible, link to) your sources, that is necessary by means of common courtesy and the terms of service here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller here is the source, https://www.mpc-forums.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=138491&start=30
Yes they did

Comment: Thanks, but: is this the exact same display? I ask because different displays have different interfaces.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes its the same display

Comment: What else is on the bus? It doesn't look like data to the LCD was captured. If the pinout is correct as labeled, the type of bus interface suggested by that pinout will be clocked by RD/WR.  The excerpted section appears unrelated: uPD72068 is a floppy disk controller.

Comment: @TimWilliams I will attach the full schematic if that's useful. For connecting that LCD connector and parallel bus, I need a clock input pin, so which one to choose RD or WR ? What about other questions please ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have attached the schematic

Comment: Which device it is? Which LCD it is? Which controller IC the LCD has?

Comment: @Justme MPC2000, the LCD is not known, and its driver is a black IC dot

Comment: @andre If you simply want to buy a brand new LCD with various colour options, you can do so. That still does not answer the question which LCD controller it has and how to emulate it, but someone is also selling an LCD kit with an interface to send the LCD contents to a PC, so that is possible too. It must be a relatively standard LCD module with relatively standard LCD controller, with 8-bit data bus, one address pin, standard 8086 read/write signal and it has two chip selects for two controllers driving such a large 248x64 dot graphics LCD.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for your input. Yes it has two controllers but they are dark chips with no IDs. Can you elabroate more on the software side please ?

Comment: @Justme Can you point out more about your investigations in an answer please ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of the major chips on the schematic turns up some likely candidates:

- IC10, [UPD70236](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/113212/NEC/UPD70236.html): V53A is an NEC branch of the Intel 8086 (via their famous V20, V30, etc. series), with various extensions including system peripherals (like DMA), expanded memory (for a total 24-bit memory space), and faster clock and instruction rates.
- IC70, IC71: DRAMs; IC20, IC30: EPROM and Flash.  Memories for CPU and peripherals.  We can see how bus signals are used here.
- Tracing back from the LCD: `IOWR` and `IORD` come direct from the CPU (buffered by IC95); `CS1` and `CS2` come from `LCD1N` and `LCD2N`, from IC72 and IC73, which decode `MION` (when low, so, when addressing IO space) and address lines 5-8 and 15:

[image]

74HC138 is a simple 3-to-8 line decoder, so one of the control signals on top becomes active when the correct inputs below are applied.

It seems the two `LCDnN` signals are exclusive, which suggests to me, there are two LCDs attached, or perhaps two controller chips working together to drive one display.

8080- and 6800-style parallel bus interfaces are fairly common among LCDs, but you will need to find out specifically how it's driven, as the control registers and graphical mapping will differ between types.

To capture or record data, all the requisite control signals must be active, and then either the falling edge, active-low level, or rising edge, of the CS and RD/WR signals will be the clock.

Most likely you would need to latch in the whole data bus, address pin, and both `LCDnN` signals.  Potentially this can be done with help of a FIFO, to read out data somewhat slower (and, yes, DMA parallel input may do the trick).

Reads will not be easy to mimic, short of an FPGA.  Perhaps you get lucky and the CPU never reads it, or more than a few easily anticipated registers.

It probably wouldn't be terrifically difficult to reverse-engineer the firmware and find where and how the LCDs are driven.  Mind, this will be a long project, but the architecture is classic and well documented, memory mapping can be read off from the schematics, and x86 disassembly is fairly trivial (it's the mapping everything out, resolving data and strings and code, and naming references, that constitutes the bulk of the work).  It may be parseable by tools like Ghidra as well, decompiling to somewhat-better-readable C, perhaps; if nothing else, mapping and referencing will be easier in such tools.

If this unit is very popular, and in need of substitute parts, code fixes, modding, or replication entirely (minding very carefully the legal outlines of such actions..), or emulation, reverse engineering will probably be needed anyway.  This would likely make up an extended community effort, hence the need for sufficient motivation to see it through.

In any case, identifying the LCD from the control signals thus applied, will not be simple.  Far easier to look inside the LCD module itself.  Up to and including decapping the blob-top and inspecting the bare die under a microscope, if applicable.  Perhaps you only need to observe data writes to figure out the graphics memory mapping and format, but it will take some luck to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, much appreciated.  Still I have question about the data part, I have a plan like to write a big state machine, once the A0 is a data register, I put the data into a buffer, as they are pixel data, if A0 contains command data, I group the commands, then act on them.
The question is I should wait first for commands, then data right ? Can you elabroate more on the software side and decoding scheme ?
Yes the LCD has two controllers but they are black dots

Comment: I will use STM32F429I, with DMA, and parallel Input, the clock will be the OR of IOWR,WR,RD, right ?